# D3.js raw-selection get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
>
> at "var headerElement = rows[0][0];"...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="./d3_lib/d3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="d3_selector.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="part2">
        <!-- Raw Selection -->
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>10:22</td>
                <td>Purchase</td>
                <td>$10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12:12</td>
                <td>Purchase</td>
                <td>$12.50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14:11</td>
                <td>Expense</td>
                <td>$9.70</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var rows = d3.selectAll("tr"); // <-- A

            console.log(rows);

            var headerElement = rows[0][0]; // <-- B

            d3.select(headerElement).attr("class", "table-header"); // <-- C

            d3.select(rows[0][1]).attr("class", "table-row-odd"); // <-- D
            d3.select(rows[0][2]).attr("class", "table-row-even"); // <-- E
            d3.select(rows[0][3]).attr("class", "table-row-odd"); // <-- F
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome console show me the "rows" at the line `console.log(rows)`;
But next line code not working...
This is the logs from from chrome console

```
>Selection {_groups: Array(1), _parents:Array(1)}
    >_groups: Array(1)
        >0: NodeList(4)
            length: 1
x> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at ~
```

Thank you for reading my Question!!

Comment: SelectAll("Tag"); give a array Nodelist and You can Select any element with index. In row[0][0] Second index in 0ne Dimensional array creates undifiend error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not encouraged. To get all nodes after a select in d3, please use `.nodes()` (as per altocumulus comment below). If all you want to do is change the classes based on whether they are a header, even or odd, you can do the following:

```
d3.selectAll("tr").attr("class", function(d, i){
    if(i == 0) {
      return "table-header"
    }
    if( i > 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
        return "table-row-odd";
    }
    return "table-row-even"
});
```

You can pass in a function, where `d` is the row and `i` is the index.
So now with `i` you can check if it is the first element, then add table-header. If not, check if it is odd or even and add the corresponding class.

https://jsfiddle.net/jfn8wkdL/2/

Comment: I'd really like to know the reasoning behind the downvote

Comment: It wasn't me either, but the first part, which before the edit was the only part, is bad practice. As per normal JS convention properties having an underscore prepended to their name should be considered private and should not be accessed from the outside. There are methods `selection.node()` and `selection.nodes()` for retrieval of the selection's nodes. The second part is really good, though, offering an alternative approach. A further hint that OP's code would have worked in v3 but no longer works in v4 because of the changes in implementation could be helpful, too.

Comment: I 'm not even aware of the breaking changes between v3 and v4, or that there is a v4. I've just taken OPs snippet, thrown it into JSFiddle, then first solved his problem and after this was done, solved it in a way that I deemed more appropriate. But I'll append those information with reference to your comment. Thank you.

Comment: I've just removed the first approach. If it is just a hacky way to not use d3's mechanisms, it should not be encouraged at all.

Comment: Much better now. One more thing, though: *"Your code should break in version 4."*... It obviously does, which is the reason the question was asked in the first place. You can tell it's v4 by looking at the type of the Selection as posted in the question. In v3 this would have been an array of arrays instead of an object. Therefore, the code would have worked if it was run using D3 v3. Probably an issue copying / re-using v3 code in v4 context.

Comment: One could think I have no clue about the d3 eco system - which I don't. Just used it a few times in small projects. Thank god there is a comment section to straighten things out